# Exercise parameterization of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

> Let $\varphi: (0, +\infty) \times (0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\varphi(r, \theta) = (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta), \theta)$, and let $S$ be the image of $\varphi$.
>
> (a) Show that $S$ is a surface, and $\varphi$ is a parametrization.
>
> (b) Calculate the first and second fundamental forms associated with the given parametrization.
>
> (c) Calculate the Gaussian curvature of $S$ at each of its points.

Here is my solution:

(a) Let's show that $\varphi$ is a parametrization: $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism with its image. It has a continuous inverse (and $\varphi$ itself is continuous):
$$
\varphi^{-1}(x, y, z) = \biggl(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2},\, z\biggr). 
$$
Additionally, $\varphi$ is differentiable, and its differential is
$$
d\varphi(r, \theta) 
= \begin{pmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\ 
\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \\ 
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
The determinant of the $2 \times 2$ leading minor is $r$, which is nonzero. Therefore, $\varphi$ is a parametrization, and it is global as $S = \operatorname{Im}, \varphi$. Thus, $S$ is a surface.

(b) We have $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r} = \bigl(\cos(\theta),\, \sin(\theta),\, 0 \bigr)$ and $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta} = \bigl(-r\sin(\theta),\, r\cos(\theta),\, 1\bigr)$.
Hence,
$$
E = \Bigl\langle\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r}, 
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r}\Bigr\rangle = 1, 
\quad 
F = \Bigl\langle\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}, \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r}\Bigr\rangle = 0, 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
G = \Bigl\langle\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}, 
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}\Bigr\rangle = r^2 + 1. 
$$
Then,
$$
N = \frac{\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r} \wedge \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}}{\left|\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial r} \wedge \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\theta}\right|} = \left(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2+1}},\, \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2+1}},\, \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}\right). 
$$
Therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
e &= \Bigl\langle N, 
\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial\theta^2} \Bigr\rangle 
= 0 \\
f &= \Bigl\langle N, 
\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial\theta\,\partial r} \Bigr\rangle 
= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+1}} \\
g &= \Bigl\langle N, 
\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial r^2} \Bigr\rangle 
= 0
\end{align}
$$

(c) Gaussian curvature:
$$
K\bigl(\varphi(r,\theta)\bigr) 
= \frac{eg - f^2}{EG - F^2} 
=-\frac{1}{(r^2 + 1)^2} 
$$
​

Comment: Not an answer, but this surface has a name: [helicoid](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Helicoid).

Comment: You switched the order of $r,\theta$ when you got to the second fundamental form.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, but luckily they are the same